# tail and ls -l inconsistency

Tags: unix

Hello I have rare situation and no sure if this really fails.

I am monitoring a file , I get the size using `ls -ald` and then i run `tail -n` command but sometime i see increase in the size but `tail -n` does not return anything.

Any clue on why this could happen.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that no process is shrinking that file?

Comment: What type of file is it?

Comment: what does `wc` say about it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are monitoring a file, then you expecting that it is being written to (growing in size)? Yes?

Try

```
tail -f -n${Number} filename
```

From `tail --help`  (on MingW)

```
-f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]
           **output appended data as the file grows**;
            -f, --follow, and --follow=descriptor are equivalent
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer